# Cloned only a single encrypted HFS+-partition, not the whole disk (ddrescue)

Tags: encryption, dd, hfs+

I cloned a single partition type HFS+ encrypted to a file image using ddrescue. The disk is not damaged, I only needed the space on the disk for something. Now I realised that I forgot to clone the partition table too.
I already tried to rebuild GPT but it failed --> I wasn't able to mount the image. Even not if I transferred the image back to the same disk.
Do you have an idea how to recover my data?